# CI EntityFramework Core missing migration check

Tags: entity-framework-core, continuous-integration, command-line-interface, entity-framework-migrations

I have an idea to add "missing migration" check to my CI pipeline. This check should validate that DbSnapshot that is present in a branch matches models in that branch (in another words, it should validate that if I will create a migration, `Up` and `Down` would be empty).

Straightforward way of doing this would be to execute `dotnet ef migrations add Test` and validate that resulting files match "empty migration" ones, but this seems like a hack.

Is there an easier way of doing this? Like `dotnet ef migrations --verify-snapshot-up-to-date` or something?

Comment: Good idea, did you find something? I'm playing with the idea of using `git status --porcelain` to verify that the model snapshot does not change when running the `migrations add Test` command. It doesn't catch changes to seed data when using either `HasData()` or custom initialization code, however. Next step would be parsing the Test migration and checking that the `Up()` is empty?

Comment: I've filed an issue, and it's currently in the backlog https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26348. Let's hope it'll get implemented some day =) I haven't implemented anything to towards this so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting EF Core 8 there's a `dotnet ef migrations has-pending-model-changes` command that does that